# How can I make an editable column in Streamlit-AGGrid, show a list of options upon double-clicking a cell value?

Tags: javascript, python, streamlit

This webpage: https://www.ag-grid.com/example , contains a grid. The "Language" column which is editable, contains a string value of a language (for example English, French etc.) on each row, that if I double click on the value of a row directly, a button appears that if I also click on it, a list of values of languages appears and when I select one, the dataframe updates the value of the row to the one I selected(in short: the column has values on rows of grid. When I double-click any of these values a button with a list appears and I can choose to change the language, then the language changes to what I've chosen). How can I replicate this effect on my streamlit app using streamlit-aggrid?

I've no idea where to start from, any recommendation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.